# Angular Directives performance issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a .NET webservice that returns an object like:

```
myObj = {
prop1: value,
prop2:value,
...
prop5:value
}
```

I created an angular service that returns this entire object(myObj).
I created 5 distinct directives to display these properties in different pages in the application(sometimes, some of them can be in the same page).
I'm calling the angular service in these directives, creating for any of them this "link" function:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            getService.getMethod().$promise.then(
                function (myObj) {
                    element.text(myObj.prop1); // .prop2, ... , prop5
                },
                function (statusCode) {
                    console.log(statusCode);
                }
            );
        }
```

I have the feeling that my approach is not the best, calling five times the angular service(through the $promise) obtaining actually the same object(myObj).
If you are interested also how the service is looking:

```
var localResource = $resource('https://.....',
    {},
    {'getAll': {method: 'JSONP', isArray: false, params: {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}}}
);

return {
    getMethod: function () {
        return localResource.getAll();
    }
}
```

Please help, if someone has an ideea haw can I improve it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can make your `getMethod` issue only one server call.

```
.factory("getService", function () {
  var getAll;
  return {
    getMethod: function () {
      if (!getAll) {
        getAll = localResource.getAll();
      }
      return getAll;
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: @StevenWexler.Thanks, it helped to other issue, but my real concerns are related to the directives, I thought that there is a way to create only one "link"(probably a controller) function and inherit it in the rest of directives, only changing the prop1, prop2...prop5 inside the function. I feel that is useless to call the service 5 times, for each of the directives, applying the promises, because starting with the first calling(for first directive) I already have all the properties, returning me the entire object.